# How to get url in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I want to get the url in php. In my root directory "myproject"->book folder/index.php file

Kindly check what I am doing:

I am accessing the url on adressbar http://localhost:8080/myproject/book/index.php?id=myurl

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;

Works Perfectly
Output: http://localhost:8080/myproject/book/index.php?id=myurl

?>
```

If I want to access http://localhost:8080/myproject/book/

The output will be:
http://localhost:8080/myproject/book/

Till now all are working fine. But I want to get url like below, remove on my index.php file the actual url will be     http://localhost:8080/myproject/book/index.php?id=myurl but I want when user hit url below

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/book/myurl
```

It can access the url http://localhost:8080/myproject/book/index.php?id=myurl but on the addressbar still url show     http://localhost:8080/myproject/book/myurl

Any idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mod_rewrite directives in Apache web-server configuration file .htaccess in the root of web-site, or nginx analog.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your webserver, here are solutions for the main 3:

Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

nginx [Rewrite rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Microsoft IIS [Rewrite rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

I think the hardest to accomplish are the ones on IIS, but all of them need some getting-used-to ... Enjoy

Most of the web frameworks have built in rewrite rules or routing with params instead of query parameters. So depending on the language and framework you're using you may not have to go through the translation yourself (which can be a pain in the ***)

Comment: @ Edwin Krause thanks for the reply. I am using apache.

Comment: Your welcome, what framework are you using? PHP obviously as language :-)

Comment: I am not using any framework. Language php. I must use laravel but this is uncompleted project given to me.

Comment: Laravel is great for routing and everything else: Best PHP framework out there! Would you please accept my answer as correct one?